# Error 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed for asmx service and WCF Rest service

Tags: iis-7.5, asmx, wcf-rest, http-verbs

We have deployed web services at http://mobile.example.com. This location has both .asmx services and WCF REST services and both these have been working great for last many days. Since yesterday we are getting error **"HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed"** whenever we make a request with verbs PUT, POST and DELETE. We googled a lot and read a lot of forums and tried many things. Many of the pointed to WedDAV module and I even disabled that module and even now we are still getting issue. Urgently need help.

**EDIT:**
DirectoryListingModule is throwing the error 405